# Passing in variables for preselection in a selection form (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm going through the example in the AROR book:
 http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/code/e1/views/app/views/test/select.rhtml

```
<% @user = "cat"

def @user.id
 4
 end

<% form_for :user do |form| %>
  <%= form.select(:name, %w{ Andy Bert Chas Dave Eric Fred }) %>
<% end %>
```

In this example, looks like @user.id is hardcoded to return 4.  I tried something like:

```
@temp = 4

def @user.id
  @temp
end
```

This didn't work...   How do I return a non global variable for this particular function?

Answer (score 1):

You must understand that when you do "def @user.id" you are actually defining a method on the singleton class associated with the @user object (the singleton class is also known as the "eigenclass" or "shadow class"). So what are doing is equivalent to this:

```
@temp = 4

class << @user
  def id
    @temp
  end
end
```

As you can see above, the @temp inside the id method definition is a regular instance variable, but it is associated with the singleton class. In other words the @temp inside the id definition is different from the @temp outside. You can deal with this by directly setting the inside @temp, like so:

```
@user.instance_variable_set(:@temp, 4)

def @user.id
  @temp
end
```

Let me know if that helps, or you have any further questions about how the singleton class works.

Answer (score 0):

This question really has nothing to do with forms, or even Ruby on Rails. It's pure Ruby.

`def @user.id; end` is a so-called singleton method (which you can read more about [here](http://www.contextualdevelopment.com/articles/2008/ruby-singleton)). Now, by default, you *cannot access* instance variables (eg. `@temp`) inside a singleton method.

There are some ways to get around this, but unless you specifically want to create a singleton method in your view (and why would you?), I'd recommend an alternative way of setting a preselect value. With your example, it should be as simple as:

```
<% form_for :user do |form| %>
  <%= form.select(:name, %w{ Andy Bert Chas Dave Eric Fred }, {:selected => @temp}) %>
<% end %>
```

As a sidenote; `@var` is an *instance* variable in Ruby--not a global variable. Global variables start with a dollar-sign (`$var`), but please don't use this unless you know what you're doing.